# Adding natbib options for PDF output

Tags: r, bookdown

Is there a way to specify `natibib` options when outputting a PDF with `bookdown`? I want the tex output to have the command

```
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
```

But there doesn't seem to be any way to specify it in the YAML. I can't add the command to my preamble, because the template already adds `\usepackage{natbib}`. What's the correct way to pass package options to `natbib`?

Comment: I guess the only way is to define your own LaTeX template: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/templates.html

Comment: @yihui I was afraid of that...

Comment: It is not that bad. Just copy Pandoc's LaTeX template, and make a single change.

Comment: @Yihui, I copied the default latex template from the [pandoc templates repository](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates) and the output document looks different. Does bookdown use a different template as the "default"?

Comment: @Yihui, I also checked the Latex template living in the `rmarkdown` package folder. It is consistent with the template on the repository, but I cannot reproduce bookdown's default style with it and I can't find an alternative latex template in the `bookdown` package folder.

Comment: bookdown uses rmarkdown's LaTeX template, which is a modified version based on Pandoc's template.

Comment: @Yihui, it looks like `bookdown` passes additional options to the default template (or something like that) when specifying `template: default` in the YAML. I cannot reproduce the document style with the template included with the `rmarkdown` package.

Answer (score 2):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/7ea49da0021c38579cd7080aec44ab4b1b7b1111), the default LaTeX template supports `natbib` options in the YAML via the variable `natbiboptions`. I presume this will propagate to `rmarkdown` when `pandoc` gets it's next official update. Until then, you can set bookdown to use the new template and pass the `geometry: "margins=1in"` to get the default bookdown pdf style with custom `natbib` options.