# Is there a way to add chapter bibliographies using bookdown?

Tags: r, latex, bookdown, bibliography

I am trying to write my PhD Thesis with bookdown and am mainly using pdf output. I have easily added a bibliography at the end of the document but would rather have a bibliography at the end of each chapter. I have tried adjusting the .tex output with LaTeX packages that allow this but this fights with the bookdoown defaults. Is there a way of adapting the .yaml options to enable this?

Comment: I'm having the same trouble but am using a word doc output (book down::word_document2). I am using the M-K rendering method, but I tried the K-M method too and it still is printing the entire bibliography at the end of each chapter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For HTML output the default is to use per-chapter bibliographies. For PDF output, I have found it is best to use the LaTeX package `biblatex` together with `biber`. Since RStudio does not know about biber, it is best to install a tool like `latexmk` and configure RStudio to use that via `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "latexmk")`. These programs might have to be installed separately, e.g. on Debian/Ubuntu/...

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra biber latexmk
```

For configuring `biblatex` the solution provided at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199336/biblatex-reference-both-by-chapter-and-at-the-end-of-the-book is appropriate.

In the end the following settings are necessary in `_output.yml`:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  citation_package: biblatex
```

In `Index.Rmd`:

```
biblio-style: authoryear
biblatexoptions: [refsegment=chapter]
```

At the end of every chapter:

```
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
```

There is no need to escape this raw LaTeX command, since `pandoc` ignores such commands for other output formats.

One can see the entire solution at

- https://github.com/rstub/bookdown-chapterbib
- https://rstub.github.io/bookdown-chapterbib/
- https://rstub.github.io/bookdown-chapterbib/bookdown-chapterbib.pdf

#### Original solution

I managed to get chapter bibliographies with PDF output using the following steps:

- Start with a copy of https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo
- copy `<R-library-path>/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex` as `book.tex` to the working directory
- update `book.tex` to use the LaTeX package `bibunits` (diff below)
- update `_output.yml` to refer to `book.tex` as `template` (diff below)
- set YAML options in `index.Rmd` (diff below)
- add code to some `Rmd` files to write `\putbib` command (diff below)

After these changes, a PDF file could be produced, but all references where missing, since `bookdown` does not know about the generated `bu?.aux` files. After executing `bibtex bu1` and `bibtex bu2`, reproducing the PDF file via `bookdown` produced a PDF with  chapter bibliographies. It is probably best to automate this step with Makefile.

Here the diff between the templates:

```
$ diff -u /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex  book.tex
--- /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex  2017-12-11 19:14:54.643867696 +0100
+++ book.tex    2018-01-16 11:43:46.182542634 +0100
@@ -93,8 +93,11 @@
 \fi
 $endif$
 $if(natbib)$
-\usepackage{natbib}
+\usepackage[$natbiboptions$]{natbib}
 \bibliographystyle{$if(biblio-style)$$biblio-style$$else$plainnat$endif$}
+\usepackage{bibunits}
+\defaultbibliographystyle{$if(biblio-style)$$biblio-style$$else$plainnat$endif$}
+\defaultbibliography{$for(bibliography)$$bibliography$$sep$,$endfor$}
 $endif$
 $if(biblatex)$
 \usepackage$if(biblio-style)$[style=$biblio-style$]$endif${biblatex}
@@ -235,6 +238,7 @@
 $endfor$

 \begin{document}
+\bibliographyunit[\chapter]
 $if(title)$
 \maketitle
 $endif$
```

And the diff of the files from `bookdown-sample`:

````
$ git diff
diff --git a/01-intro.Rmd b/01-intro.Rmd
index 6b16e73..1a5f9de 100644
--- a/01-intro.Rmd
+++ b/01-intro.Rmd
@@ -19,3 +19,5 @@ knitr::kable(
 ```

 You can write citations, too. For example, we are using the **bookdown** package [@R-bookdown] in this sample book, which was built on top of R Markdown and **knitr** [@xie2015].
+
+`r if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) '\\putbib'`
diff --git a/02-literature.Rmd b/02-literature.Rmd
index 00745d0..983696e 100644
--- a/02-literature.Rmd
+++ b/02-literature.Rmd
@@ -1,3 +1,6 @@
 # Literature

 Here is a review of existing methods.
+[@R-knitr]
+
+`r if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) '\\putbib'`
diff --git a/_output.yml b/_output.yml
index 342a1d6..cc8afb1 100644
--- a/_output.yml
+++ b/_output.yml
@@ -14,4 +14,5 @@ bookdown::pdf_book:
   latex_engine: xelatex
   citation_package: natbib
   keep_tex: yes
+  template: book.tex
 bookdown::epub_book: default
diff --git a/index.Rmd b/index.Rmd
index 4e21b9d..2fdb813 100644
--- a/index.Rmd
+++ b/index.Rmd
@@ -7,6 +7,8 @@ output: bookdown::gitbook
 documentclass: book
 bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
 biblio-style: apalike
+natbiboptions: sectionbib
+graphics: yes
 link-citations: yes
 github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
 description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
````

Answer (score 13):

For a latex-specific solution see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300144/82573), i.e. use the `sectionbib` option for `natbib` and load the `chapterbib` package. You will need to edit The bookdown template to set the required options for `natbib` and tell bookdown to use your custom template in the yaml. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770287/adding-natbib-options-for-pdf-output) for more info on the bookdown template.

I swear I saw instructions in the bookdown docs for doing this with gitbook format, but I can't seem to find it...

**EDIT** I went and looked at an old bookdown project of mine. For `gitbook` output, you specify the following in `_output.yml`:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  split_by: chapter
  split_bib: yes
```

Which will (you guessed it) split the bibliography by chapter. I'm actually a bit surprised that bookdown doesn't support the equivalent options for `bookdown::pdf_book` yaml options, but should be easy enough to do by setting up `sectionbib`/`chapterbib` in the [LaTeX preamble](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html).

Comment: there seems to be an issue with the preamble approach: `chapterbib` wants each chapter to be an `\include`d file, each containing the `bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` commands, whereas bookdown produces a single .tex file.