# R bookdown: list of abbreviations with LaTeX nomenclature package

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Generating an index in R bookdown works perfectly well.

Adding a list of abbreviations with the nomenclature package is more difficult:
I added to `preamble.tex`

```
\usepackage{nomenclature}
\makenomenclature
```

And then I include a file calling the `\printnomenclature` macro via the `after_body` include option in the yaml header.

Actually, I already have a pretty good idea, what the problem is:
Usually, one calls `makeindex` when generating the nomenclature list with LaTeX. This magically works for the index, but for the nomenclature package, there seems to be a need for some manual work.

Answer (score 0):

Since RStudio does not know about special `makeindex` calls, you could install a tool like `latexmk` and configure RStudio to use that by putting `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "latexmk")` somewhere in your main `Rmd` file, c.f.
[Is there a way to add chapter bibliographies using bookdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028623/is-there-a-way-to-add-chapter-bibliographies-using-bookdown/48262127#48262127)

[Not tested since you do not provide a minimal example.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I can't really find an call in the post on the chapter bibliographies which is similar to the `makeindex` call. I thought that RStudio would use `latexmk` by default.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki The calls are implicitly done by RStudio. However, you can change which program is called, c.f. https://github.com/rstub/bookdown-chapterbib/blob/master/index.Rmd