# Bookdown chapter bibliographies .csl file MSWord/PDF

Tags: ms-word, pdf-generation, bookdown, csl

My desired output is both an (1) MSWord and (2) PDF document, both with (a) in-text citations, (b) citations in some footnotes/endnotes, (c) chapter bibliographies, and (d) cumulative bibliography, (a)-(d) according to the .csl file,  [Springer - Humanities (author-date)](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=id%3Aspringer-humanities-author-date).

My tools are: .Rmd files, bookdown, LibreOffice, Zotero.

My problem:

- IF(MSWord output) {**NO** chapter bibliographies}
- IF(PDF output **AND** chapter bibliographies) {`citation_package: natbib` **OR** `citation_package: biblatex`}
- IF(PDF output **AND** .csl file) {`citation_package: none`}
- I hope to avoid breaking the book into separate bookdown projects for each chapter---this is annoying manual work and some chapters build R objects that are used in subsequent chapters (so it would be required rewriting code and caching things, etc.).

Attempted solutions:

- I have successfully implemented both the biblatex and the natbib solutions to "bookdown + chapter bibliographies + PDF" here, but that solves one part of my problem: [Is there a way to add chapter bibliographies using bookdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028623/is-there-a-way-to-add-chapter-bibliographies-using-bookdown)
- I have successfully implemented the solution to "bookdown + .csl file + PDF" here, but that solves one part of my problem: [use csl-file for pdf-output in bookdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965247/use-csl-file-for-pdf-output-in-bookdown/49145699#49145699)

Notes

- The PDF output will be considered a reference document, **thus solving the MSWord document problem is the priority** (which may involve manually copying and pasting from the PDF output).
- Technically, I'm also using the `documentclass: svmono` (where `author/svmono.cls` is here: [Springer LaTeX2e macro packages for monographs](https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/monographs) and no "Humanities" `.bst` file is offered)